# bootstrap media query for navbar isnt working

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to overide bootstrap's media query and it seams no matter what i do, nothing is willing to work.

This is the code that wont work for me

```
@media  (max-width : 1200px) {
  .navbar{
      width: 90%;
  }​
}
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML too

Comment: Are you loading this before or after bootstrap? :)

Comment: Try using `!important`, or make your own navbar class. You can get Bootstraps css from the dev tools, and change what you want.

Comment: make your own class with styles you need! use `!important` when nothing else helps

Answer (score 0):

Please Provide Your HTML,

try **!important** to Overwrite the Property.it will give priority to your overridden Code

Answer (score 0):

Solved by @Drew_Kennedy:

> Try using `!important`, or make your own navbar class. You can get
>   Bootstraps css from the dev tools, and change what you want.

I made an example for you based on his comment:

---

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/124jr118/)

CSS:

```
@media  (max-width : 1200px) {
  .navbar{
      width: 90% !important;
  }
}
```

For other [examples of when to use !important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)